# React Hydration Error While Using Map Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have been learning React/Next JS and i'm putting together a basic table that dynamically populates based on an array of items from this public API endpoint: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

It is working fine fetching this data, only i'm getting a react-hydration-error related to my array.map function I believe. I assume this is to do with the disparity between the async-await function, and the rest of the rendered component but i'm not sure how to go about fixing this while having identical functionality.

The error is:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Component Stack
table
section
main
div
Layout
Home
App

The code for my index.js is:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Layout, { siteTitle } from '../components/layout';
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {entries: data}, 
  }
}



export default function Home({entries}) {
  return (
    <Layout home>
      <Head>
        <title>{siteTitle}</title>
      </Head>
      <section className={utilStyles.headingMd}>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Completed</th>
          </tr>
          {entries.map(entry => (
            <div key = {entry.id}>
              <tr>
                <td><a><h3>{entry.title}</h3></a></td>
                <td><a><h3>{JSON.stringify(entry.completed)}</h3></a></td>
              </tr>
            </div>
          ))};
        </table>
      </section>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

The code for my layout.js is simply:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from './layout.module.css';
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';
import Link from 'next/link';

const name = 'Email Dashboard';
export const siteTitle = 'Email Dashboard';

export default function Layout({ children, home }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        
      </Head>
      <header className={styles.header}>
        {home ? (
          
            <h1 className={utilStyles.heading2Xl}>{name}</h1>
          
        ) : (
            <h1 className={utilStyles.heading2Xl}>{name}</h1>
        )}
      </header>
      <main>{children}</main>
      {!home && (
        <div className={styles.backToHome}>
          <Link href="/">← Back to home</Link>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Let me know if you require any further information, or if you're able to provide an easy fix, thank you

I have tried gradually removing parts of the  to completely remove references to the list, and just write in static-text placeholders and I still get hydration issues. I'm not sure on the source of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the div tag from the tag table

maybe you can change it to be like this:

```
<section className={utilStyles.headingMd}>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Completed</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {entries.map(entry => (
         <tr key = {entry.id}>
           <td><a><h3>{entry.title}</h3></a></td>
           <td><a><h3>{JSON.stringify(entry.completed)}</h3></a></td>
         </tr>
      ))};
      </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```